# How to not display KeyStorePassword on the command line?

Tags: linux, https, playframework-2.3

when configuring https for play framework, I have to use following configuration when running the background task.

```
play -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=keystore.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=password run
```

I don't want to display the keystore password on the command line. It shouldn't be visible for all users on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS configuration can either be supplied using system properties or in `application.conf`

I recommend to use a combination of environment variables and the `application.conf`

1. Put your sensitive information in environment variables
2. Reference these environment variables from the `application.conf`:

Like this:

```
https.keyStore = defaultvalue
https.keyStore = ${?MY_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_ENV}
```

The question mark means that if there is no value found for `MY_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_ENV` then the *defaultvalue* from above will be used